# Is it possible to see how many users are authenticated by google, facebook, twitter or anonymous signed-up from Firebase Console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

In realtime database I have exactly 448101 users that authenticated by different providers. Is there any easy way to filter how many users sign-up with facebook, twitter, google or anonymous-login? I believe this feature should be in the analytics section of firebase console.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature in the Firebase Console at the moment. But it sounds reasonable, so I suggest you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

In the meantime: since you say you have the users in the database, you might be able to derive the data from there, or at least start tracking it there.